# Distribute per 4.5th percentile for new scale - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have currently 511 rows with a field called "value" where the scale is between 250k and 70+ million, which is the item of the row's price. I want to change the scale so that it will only be between 5 and 16 instead (0.5 per jump, so 5 to 5.5 to 6 to 6.5 etc..)

My initial idea was to distribute via percentile. So top 1-4.5% will get new value in a new field of 16, top 4.5-9% will get 15.5 and so on until we reached 5.

I've been trying to playaround in SQL and also searched for help without any result. Perhaps any of you have any better idea or can make my idea into reality? I'm willing to write the same SQL query 50 times with changed values if that's what is required. As long as it solves the problem!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can calculate the boundaries of each range first, you can then do:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET value = 
    CASE WHEN value > 95.5%value THEN 16
         WHEN value > 91%value THEN 15.5
         WHEN value > 86.5%value THEN 15
         ...
         WHEN VALUE > 4.5%value THEN 5.5
         ELSE 5
    END
```

Replace all the `xxx%value`s with the boundaries that you calculated earlier.